# Record audio streaming with Ruby (on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, audio-recording

I need to record some radio programs and make them available for later listening.

I have looked into the [Shoutcast API](http://dev.aol.com/SHOUTcast/getting-started) for getting the audio streams resources, but don't have a clue how to **record an audio broadcast and save it in an audio file**.

I'm looking for any Ruby libraries, or even some information on how to get started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the stream in a file, for example :

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'


url = URI.parse('http://your.stream.domain.com/')

Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) do |http|       
        f = open("saved_stream.mp3", "w")
        begin
            http.request_get('/stream_path.mp3') do |resp|              
            resp.read_body do |segment|
                f.write(segment)                 
            end
            end
        ensure
            f.close()
        end     
    end
```