# Converting audio file to byte array in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, audio, paperclip, arrays, audio-streaming

I have been using Grape for Restful api requests for our Ruby on rails application. 
I have a requirement of doing an audio attachment for my blogs.

What is the best way of sending an attachment to my API requests.

How to convert an audio attachment to bytearray.

Comment: Hi, not a ruby expert but, with REST, you can pass "object" data (as json) with a POST request. Technically, in REST terms, a POST request should be reserved for passing new data or writing data to the server through a write API. Not sure if that fits your use case. Nevertheless, as a starter for ten, here's a [link that might help](https://www.socialtext.net/open/very_simple_rest_in_ruby_part_3_post_to_create_a_new_workspace)

Comment: Hi, i am using Grape for sending API requests. For images i am sending  the encoded base64 strings and doing the paperclip attachment from rails side. For audio attachments i am thinking to send a byte array of audio which from rails side i will save it. But dont know how to get a byte array of an audio ?

Comment: Ok, have you checked out these two posts that seem to be relevant? [record-audio-streaming-with-ruby-on-rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7496110/record-audio-streaming-with-ruby-on-rails?rq=1) and [ruby-how-to-represent-message-length-as-2-binary-bytes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13794817/ruby-how-to-represent-message-length-as-2-binary-bytes?rq=1).